# Configuration of thymeleaf text template in spring boot application.properties failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, thymeleaf

I'm trying to configure a simple thymeleaf text template in my spring boot configuration and got to the point where the thymeleaf variable placeholder and the spring boot configuration property placeholder interfer (afaik both use the SpEL) when the template contains a colon (e.g. "[(${#dates.format(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')})]" as spring boot tries to resolve the variable "#dates.format(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH" but uses default value "mm')" instead.

I tried to change the spring boot prefix of the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, but then some of my included libraries no longer work as they use the ${} variables

Is there a way to extend thymeleaf to treat %{} like ${} ?

I want to avoid replacing the template i read from the config, as i configure those templates on various properties and classes

ad1: For configuration i use a custom mechanism that converts a xml file into yaml which will then be used for configuration, so basically you can say its a application.yml configuration file. I cannot use custom template files in this scenario as the customer must be able to configure the template in a custom xml editor. The templates are all just a few words (like the subject of an email e.g.)

Comment: By default, Spring+Thymeleaf uses SpEL indeed: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html. I am however struggling to understand why would you want to configure templates this way? all the docs I could find, suggest storing templates in a separate folder, this way Spring boot will not try to resolve them. and you could keep the path and the filename(s) to templates configured via application properties. can you share a reproducible sample?

Comment: also which properties mechanism do you use: yaml, properties file, something else?

Comment: the thing is, that for this project we use a xml config file which is then converted to yaml and consumed by the program. this is due to the fact as the customer has to be able to configure the application using a already existing custom xml editor and has to be able to configure the whole application with the same editor (thats also why i need the template in the config file). The templates are all rather small (few words).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can protect your expression by wrapping certain placeholders, thus hiding them from Spring Boot `PropertyResolver` mechanism:

application.properties:

```
test-template=[(#{'$'}{#dates.format(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')})]
```

see full working code here: https://github.com/62mkv/spring-properties-thymeleaf.

This solution is "loaned" from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/9628

Answer (score 1):

Thank you 62mkv, this seems to usually be the solution, thats why i marked it as the answer.
Anyways it wasn't the solution in my case, as it still didnt work, which is because of the way i load the config using a custom PropertySourceLoader

```
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PICONFIG.class);
        PICONFIG config = (PICONFIG) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(resource.getInputStream());
        YAMLFactory factory = new YAMLFactory();
        //factory.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String yaml = mapper.writeValueAsString(config);
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer c;

        return  new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(name,new ByteArrayResource(yaml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

I now decided to just use [(@{})] for my text templates and then replace the @ in the setter of the configuration bean, which seems to work so far and wasn't to big of as issue as i refactored my code to use a common configuration class for the templates